# Indentation in javascript filter HAML

Tags: haml, erb

I used HAML for my app and add some javascript code in the view.

Follow [this tutorial](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter), I add `:javascript` before my script and it worked.

But it'll better if I can indent my javascript code. Haml don't understand the indent after *:javascript* tag and raise error.

Any solution for this problem? Please share, thanks

Comment: Do you mean you ide or text redactor has error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the issue. `haml` will preserve the indentation level. For example,

```
%html
  %head
    :javascript
      function bar() {
        console.log("bar");                                                     
      }
```

will be transformed into

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function bar() {
        console.log("bar");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

As you can see, indentation is quite well understood - as long as you obey the rules and have the code properly indented inside `:javascript`.

Comment: Sorry for noise, after restart my server, it worked. I don't understand the problem also.